# Java swing problem transparent animation gif

Tags: java, swing, gif, transparent, animated-gif

Why in java when I try to use a transparent gif animation its image is distorted or has pixel inconsistency?  I wanted to make sure if the problem was Jlabel's problem, but I showed the gif in different components and the same problem appeared. The gif has already been checked many times in other environments and looks completely fine.

**Code**
Example of how I display the image

```java
JLabel labelPokemonIcon = new JLabel();
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/app/pokemon/gif/" + nameIcon));
labelPokemonIcon.setIcon(imageIcon);
```

**Gif original**

[gif animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLyB0.gif)

[gif animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/legJG.gif)

**JAVA SWING**

[component swing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITaqb.png)

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with the original image on a Windows machine. A part of the background of the animated image is cycling through some opaque colors (as shown with yellow in your case). But opening this image with the browser and a simple image viewer does not have these background colors.

Comment: Probably a dup of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331052/18157 but I'm not positive.  For more, search the web for _"jlabel animated gif transparent background"_

Comment: You need some way to modify the disposal methods of the frames, some are set to `restoreToBackgroundColor` while some are set to `doNotDispose`

Comment: @gthanop What do you think the problem is?

Comment: After reading some related posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223809/6746785) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31979929/6746785)) I believe the problem is that the encoding of the original GIF you are using is not fully supported by AWT (because of its advanced compression method AFAIU). So I tried to *unoptimize* the GIF: I uploaded it [here](https://ezgif.com/repair) and clicked *Submit* after selecting *ImageMagick coalesce (unoptimize)* as the repair method. The new GIF worked with `ImageIcon` (but has about a +10% size penalty). That's only a temporary workaround though.

Comment: @gthanop It worked, I think it's better this way instead of creating a complex code.

Comment: Great. I am glad it helped. If indeed the problem is the support of such GIF encodings in AWT then this would be the root cause and that's why I am thinking that downgrading/unoptimizing the GIF would then only be a workaround. Haha.

Comment: @gthanop In fact, the gif does not lose its quality. It remains the same. Only this time with the errors corrected.